# Android View error

Tags: java, android, view

I am getting the following two errors located in my code below `(CheckBox) v.isChecked();`:

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from CheckBox to boolean**

**The method isChecked() is undefined for the type View**

```
for(final int i = 0; i < setOfCheckBoxes.length; i++){

                                                setOfCheckBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
      public void onClick(View v) {      
     selected[i] = (CheckBox) v.isChecked();
     }
   });
 }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method calls bind tighter in order of operations than casts. Try this:

```
selected[i] = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
```

Edit: Regarding the use of 'i' in the inner class, use a separate variable for the captured index and the loop iteration. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < setOfCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
    final int index = i;
    setOfCheckBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
        public void onClick(View v) {      
            selected[index] = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: its weird I tried that but then I get the error under my i++ "The final local variable i cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment"   I cant remove final because I use it inside an inner class.  Not sure why those two are effecting each other?

Comment: Edited for this other issue. :)

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue and based on the discussion below helps me understand why.

Answer (score 1):

adamp is correct.  You must do:

```
selected[i] = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
```

However, you are getting a problem with your variable "i" because it is final.  Move "int i = 0" to outside whatever function this code is in (make it a global variable).  This will allow you to use it inside the inner class as well.

Comment: While this will work, it's bad form to make something like this into a field just to capture the value. Declaring another final variable with the same value within the loop will solve it.

Comment: I agree that its "bad form", but it is worse form to rapidly instantiate and destroy a "final" variable inside of a loop purely for this purpose.

Comment: Mobile dev forces tough decisions in the name of performance?  :P

Comment: It doesn't instantiate anything in the sense of object creation, at worst it's another int on the stack. The compiler doesn't allow capturing the value of non-final variables. Think of it like passing the value of 'i' to the anonymous inner class's constructor and saving it in a final field within the inner class.

Comment: I completely disagree.  It causes the garbage collector to have to create, track, and delete a new variable every single iteration.  This adds an incredible amount of unnecessary overhead when one variable can be reused repeatedly.  There is a reason no one wants to declare variables inside loops.

Comment: Primitive types only exist on the stack. There is nothing for the GC to track here aside from the View.OnClickListener being explicitly created with 'new'.